# If $f:(X,d) \rightarrow (X,d)$ is a Lipschitz function, then $f$ is continuous, proved using open-ball-based definition of continuity

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $f:(X,d) \rightarrow (X,d)$ is a Lipschitz function, then f is continuous

**proof**

If  $C=0 $, f is constant and therefore continuous.

Let  $C>0 $, if  $p_0 \in X $ and if $\epsilon >0$, if we put  $\delta =\epsilon/C$, we get $f(B_d(p_0,\delta)) \subseteq B_d(f(p_0),\epsilon)$.

**Now I do it like this, using the traditional  definition of continuity :**

For the case $C>0$
I take $\delta =\epsilon/C$ if $d(p,p_0)<\delta=\epsilon/C$, and by the definition of Lipschitz function $d(f(p),f(p_0))<Cd(p,p_0) $ and therefore $d(f(p),f(p_0))<Cd(p,p_0)<C.\epsilon/C=\epsilon $

**And I also now that the following are equivalent definitions of continuity, I am using the first one, they are using the second one:**

Let $f:(X,d)\rightarrow (Y,d') $  $f$ is continuous in $p_0 \in X$ if then $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta >0$, such that $d(p,p_0)<\delta $ then $d'(f(p),f(p_0))<\epsilon$

Let $f:(X,d)\rightarrow (Y,d') $  $f$ is continuous in $p_0 \in X$ if then $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta >0$, such that $f(B_d(p_0,\delta)) \subseteq B_{d'}(f(p_0),\epsilon)$

**I am trying to get familiar with the second one, so my question is how do they go directly from $\delta =\epsilon/C$, to the inclusion $f(B_d(p_0,\delta)) \subseteq B_d(f(p_0),\epsilon)$ , without doing my way?. Is there some direct easy reasoning that allows me write the conclusion directly once the epsilon has been chosen?**

Answer (score 1):

You have done exactly what needs to be done. Think for a moment, what does the statement $f(B_d(p_0, \delta))\subseteq B_{d’}(f(p_0), \epsilon)$ actually mean and how could one go about proving such a statement?

After thinking for a moment you realise that the way to prove such a statement would be to actually take any point $p\in B_d(p_0, \delta)$ and show that $f(p) \in B_{d’}(f(p_0), \epsilon)$. This is exactly what you have shown. Note that a point $p\in B_d(p_0, \epsilon)$ if and only if $d(p_0, p)<\delta$ and similarly $f(p) \in B_{d’}(f(p_0), \epsilon)$ if and only if $d’(f(p), f(p_0))<\epsilon.$
This is what you have shown.

Comment: Actually I' d like to know if there is some easy reasoning that allows me to write it directly without having to prove it that way, since the author directly states the result without any warning that intermediate steps are omitted, and they do it often when using balls in continuity

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $z\in f(B_d(p_0,\delta))$. Let us show $z\in B_d(f(p_0),\epsilon)$. Well $z=f(x)$ for some $x\in B_d(p_0,\delta)$. Then $d(x,p_0)<\delta$. Therefore, $d(f(x),f(p_0)) \le d(x,p_0)\cdot C < C\cdot \delta =\epsilon$ by the definition of a Lipschitz function and using our choice of $\delta$. In other words, $d(z,f(p_0))<\epsilon$, so $z\in B_d(f(p_0),\epsilon))$ by definition.